# Слово "злопыхатель"

Tags: этимология

Интересна этимология слова "злопыхатель". Корель "зло" — это понятно, а что за "пыхатель"?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Пыхатель" от глагола "пыхать" (инфинитив у глагола "пышет". пышут"). Злопыхатель - злом пышет.

Comment: Инфинитив - это как раз пЫхать. 
А пЫшу, пЫшет, пЫшут - личные формы.

Comment: Да Виктор это и имел в виду, он в скобках как раз поясняет, что такое "пыхать"

Comment: Возможно. Но я предпочитаю исходить из написанного, а не из "имеет в виду". И я вижу личные формы, названные инфинитивом.

Answer (score 0):

П**ы**хать - гдагол многозначный. Полагаю, что здесь используется это значение:

1. П**Ы**ХАТЬ, п**ы**шу, п**ы**шешь; п**ы**шущий; нсв. Разг.
   ....
2. чем.
   Проявлять, выражать что-л. в сильной степени, излучать, испускать. П. злобой. Здоровьем пышешь, как я погляжу. Взгляд так и пышет страстью. [] безл. От вас пышет благополучием. < Пыхнуть, -ну, -нёшь; св. Однокр. (2 зн.). Пыхнуло жаром.
   (БТС)

Есть еще значение с дургой парадигмой спряжения:

1. ПЫХАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Разг.
   Выпускать струи воздуха, пара, газа, дыма (обычно с шумом, пыхтеньем). На столе пыхает самовар. Пыхая паром, прошёл паровоз. П. сигареткой
   (курить). < Пыхнуть, -ну, -нёшь; св. Однокр. Газ пыхнул и потух.
   (там же)

В принципе его тоже можно принять во анимание, особенно учитывая образования "пыхатель", а не ?"пы**ш**атель".